# curl POST -F to php cUrl

Tags: php, curl

I'm attempting to POST a local file to an API, it works if I use command line curl but not when I try using php cURL. I set up some variables for the headers and body

```
$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Authorization: Passcode '.$passcode;
$headers[] = 'FileType: STD';

$api_url = 'https://url.com';
$field_json = json_encode($field).';type=application/json'
$filepath = realpath('path/file.csv');
$file = new CURLFile($filepath,'text/csv');
```

curl based on the API's specifications  works if I set it as a string and use exec

```
$cmd = "curl -X POST -H \"$headers[0]\" -H \"$headers[1]\" -F \"field=$field_json\" -F \"filename=@$filepath\" $api_url";

exec($cmd,$result); //This works successfully
```

but when I attempt to send the POST using the following code with PHP cURL, I get a vague error response 'Unexpected error'

```
    $body = array(
            'field' => $field_json,
            'filename' => $file
            );

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $api_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD, FALSE);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
    echo json_encode($result);
```

I'm using PHP 5.5.9 and have tried it using the old way with @ and the filepath.